# How to compile Android Studio project in Android 4.X source code environment

Tags: android

In my Android project I used some Support Library such as RecyclerView, Leanback, Cardview. etc.. My buildToolsVersion is 23.0.1, targetSdkVersion is 23

I try to compile RecyclerView, Leanback, Cardview in Eclipse, but Eclipse support for some new Android Support Library has been very unfriendly. I try it in Eclipse Juno but compile failed because Eclipse Juno use jdk1.7 and don't support Android-23, so I update to Eclipse Mars and use jdk1.8 and try it again. I expectantly Eclipse Mars can support Android-23 but I found no devices when I change to DDMS tab. I suspect the reason is the version of adb, but I check the adb is the latest version, my Android SDK version is the lastst too. Finally I try to use the latest version of ADT but still failed.

Now my project's trouble is I have to compile my project in the Android 4.X source code environment. In order to compile project successfully I make a Android.mk and add LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES to ensure some jars can be found. But When I use Android Studio how can I found out where is the jars which I add some comple 'xxx' statement in build.gradle.

Summarize:
  Above that so much, I encountered two troubles:

1) I hope to be able to use the latest version of Android Support Library 23.0.1(RecyclerView, Leanback, Cardview) in Eclipse. So I can copy and paste the jars to compile my project in the Android 4.X source code environment at any time any where.

2) I hope to find out all of jar library which I add in build.gradle.

End) Android 4.X source code environment use jdk1.6, and I want use Android Support Library 23.0.1 in the environment. I need your help, thanks.

Comment: Eclipse Juno supports android-23 just fine.  The problem is probably how you're trying to use the RecyclerView and CardView libraries.  Doing it in eclipse is tricky, there is no supported way to do it. I did it recently by finding a library project on github that someone made by extracting the jar and resources from the aar file for each library, and it works just fine.

Comment: I haved open the project android-sdk/extras/android/support/v7/recyclerview to eclipse, delete the project's file libs/android-support-v7-recyclerview.jar, and then extract android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/23.0.1recyclerview-v7-23.0.1-sources.jar to the project's src folder, last copy android-sdk/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar to the project's libs folder. Now it works just fine.